# IllegalArgument error while generated by Thrift Compiler

Tags: java, thrift

while I execute the command like thrift -r --gen java tutorial.thrift; in the file tutorial.thrift I defined something like this.

```
exception IllegalArgument {
  1: string message;
}
```

then generate gen-java.

when I tried to write code... something wrong with the IllegalArgument...

How can I solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWUzc.png)

Comment: Did you specify namespace for Java in tutorial.thrift?

Comment: while I correct the classpath to compile the files below the gen-java folder...  it comes to the problem from IllegalArgument... it says cannot find a method of.main(String[]) ... which means compiles error